# NSDate and time from string

Tags: ios, nsdate

i've a following format date

October 19, 2011 1:00pm (dateData) has this value

how can I convert it to NSDate

following code does not work

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
 NSString* dateData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.itemDate, self.itemTime];
  NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateData];      
  [dateFormat release];
```

i've tried with both NSDateFormatterLongStyle and NSDateFormatterFullStyle

Comment: I can convert October 19, 2011 to valid NSDate fine with NSDateFormatterLongStyle

Comment: This works     [format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mma"];

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in the original post is that your string formatter is pretty much contains nothing meaningful. Follow the following tutorial: http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/19/nsdate-tutorial-create-a-nsdate-from-a-string-or-from-nsdatecomponents/

But pretty much update your stringWithFormat and you should be set.